# Code doesn't display the correct output

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have written this code in java to view information about the header and different server requests. But it shows Mozilla Firefox as by browser while I am running the code in eclipse browser. It shows same when I run it on chrome. Also it does not give the correct processor information as it is showing AMD as my processor while I have intel. I am using tomcat and eclipse.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Headers<hr/>");
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
        out.print("Header Name : <em>" + headerName);
        out.print("</em>, Header Value : <em>" + headerValue);
        out.println("</em><br/>");
    }
    StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    String host = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(uri));
    out.println("Host : " + request.getServerName()+"</br>");
    out.println("Port : " + request.getServerPort()+"</br>");
    out.print("URL : "+host);
    out.println(uri);
    out.println(getServletContext().getServerInfo());
    out.println(getServletContext().getRealPath(request.getServletPath()));
}
```

Comment: The header is just as it is sent from your browser. There is no relation to Tomcat or Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Because eclipse browser use mazilla core(or User-Agent says so), what about processor, I think it only give you a architecture of the CPU, but not the real type

Comment: When I executed it on google chrome, still it showed Mozilla Firefox as the browser

Comment: You can change User-Agent with plugin to what you want, for example you can imitate the mobile access while you use your PC

Comment: As mentioned above, your browser can send whatever it wants or as you configured it. There is no correct or incorrect "output".

Comment: The client tells to you who it is, you can believe or not, it not a standard to obey strictly, it is only a convention, and I wander if with  default settings the Chrome will say that he is a Mazilla `Firefox`